# Issue with Angular $http API

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest

I have an angular service consuming a resource from the .NET based WEB API service.

I am using Angular `$http` along with the params object to pass the required params to the WEB API. I get an `401 Unauthorized error`. But If I use the `$resource` API, this request goes through. I am unable to figure out the issue as I have other service calls where `$http` is successful.

Here is the code

```
function getParts(lineCode,partNo){

    return $resource(URLs.BASE + "/api/RPP/GetVehiclePart", { lineCode: lineCode, partNo: partNo }, {
        query: { method: 'GET', withCredentials: true }
    });

}
```

Above works but the below doesn't

```
function getParts(lineCode,partNo){
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: URLs.BASE + "/api/Rpp/GetVehiclePart?lineCode="+lineCode+"&partNo="+partNo,
       withCredentials: true
    }).then(_successHandler, _errorHandler);

}
```

Comment: please edit your question so that the code snippets are correctly formatted :-)